# Error when used org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use Json converter in Kafka connect but it is throwing below error :

```
{"type":"log", "host":"connecttest6-ckaf-connect-84866788d4-p8lkh", "level":"ERROR", "neid":"kafka-connect-4d9495b82e1e420992ec44c433d733ad", "system":"kafka-connect", "time":"2019-04-08T11:55:14.254Z", "timezone":"UTC", "log":"pool-5-thread-1 - org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask - WorkerSinkTask{id=hive-sink6-1} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception"}
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter cannot be cast to io.confluent.connect.hdfs.Format
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:242)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:103)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:98)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:302)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried following configuration for Json (key.converter.enable.schema=false and value.converter.enable.schema=false) in source and same in HDFSSinkConnector configuration.

**Connect configuration:**

```
 ConnectKeyConverter: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  ConnectValueConverter: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  ConnectKeyConverterSchemasEnable: "true"
  ConnectValueConverterSchemasEnable: "true"
 "http(s)://schemareg_headless_service_name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:port"
  ConnectSchemaRegistryUrl: "http://kafka-schema-registry-ckaf-schema-registry-headless.ckaf.svc.cluster.local:8081"
  ConnectInternalKeyConverter: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  ConnectInternalValueConverter: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
```

**REST API command used to add sink(Sink Configuration):**

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector","tasks.max":"2","topics":"topic-test","hdfs.url": "hdfs://localhost/tmp/jsontest4","flush.size": "3","name": "thive-sink6","format.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter","value.converter.schemas.enable":"false","key.converter.schemas.enable":"false"}' connecttest6-ckaf-connect.ckaf.svc.cluster.local:8083/connectors/hive-sink6/config
```

After adding the sink to Kafka Connect.I sent the data to respective Kafka topic. Below are the data I tried :

```
{"name":"test"}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","field":"name"}]},"payload":{"name":"value1"}}
```

The data is expected to be written in HDFS location provided in Sink Configuration mentioned above.

Need suggestions on above scenario and how the error can be resolved.

Comment: How are you running Kafka Connect? What worker configuration file have you quoted there? It doesn't look like a `.properties` or `.json`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if somewhere in your configurations (for Kubernetes??), you've assigned `format.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`, which isn't valid.

Perhaps you meant to use `io.confluent.connect.hdfs.json.JsonFormat`

Comment: Thank you @cricker_007 for the suggesstion. It worked as expected.